# Simulink Coder Error related to path (I believe)

Tags: matlab, simulink, embedded-coder

I am learning to use Simulink Coder to convert my models into C++ code. Since I'm starting with this, I am following some Simulink examples. However, I keep getting an error even when following their step-by-step guide. The error is the one in the picture.

Error message

[image: 1].

I spent a few hours making sure it wasn't related to the configuration for C/C++ Code generation, but it seems all good. I also found something online saying it could be related to the PATH system variable. The path shown in the picture (validation error) is about 10 lines long, begin those 2 lines just the beginnings.

Does anyone know what could be happening here?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full error, as text not an image. It would probably be helpful to link to the tutorial you're trying to follow too.

Comment: Can you try clearing temporary folders like slprj?